# frame size and hop size mismatch with aubio pitch detection algo

Tags: audio, pitch, detection

I am writing a script that detects the pitch of a short file as part of a larger project.  I want to detect using an external call to sox and using the crepe, aubio, and librosa libraries.  Aubio is giving me a headache. I have 3 calls from it:

```
aubio_pitch_mid = run_aubio_pitch(base_prep_192k32b_data_path, sr, method='fcomb')
aubio_pitch_large = run_aubio_pitch(base_prep_192k32b_data_path, sr, method='yinfft'
```

to a function:

```
def run_aubio_pitch(base_prep_192k32b_data_path, tolerance=0.8, method='default'):
    audio, sr = sf.read(base_prep_192k32b_data_path)  # Reads file and converts to 'float32'
    audio = audio.astype(np.float32)  # Cast audio to float32
    pitch_o = aubio.pitch(method, 2048, 512, sr)
    pitch_o.set_tolerance(tolerance)
    samples = np.array([pitch_o(samples.astype(np.float32))[0] for samples in librosa.frames_to_samples(librosa.util.frame(audio, frame_length=2048, hop_length=512))])
    return samples
```

working on a 192k32b audio file.  I got this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rich/Dropbox/audio/recording/rich rath/OwenTheGeek/wavetables/create/wvtbl.py", line 361, in <module>
    aubio_pitch_small = run_aubio_pitch(base_prep_192k32b_data_path, sr, method='yin')
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rich/Dropbox/audio/recording/rich rath/OwenTheGeek/wavetables/create/wvtbl.py", line 218, in run_aubio_pitch
    samples = np.array([pitch_o(samples.astype(np.float32))[0] for samples in librosa.frames_to_samples(librosa.util.frame(audio, frame_length=512, hop_length=512))])
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/rich/Dropbox/audio/recording/rich rath/OwenTheGeek/wavetables/create/wvtbl.py", line 218, in <listcomp>
    samples = np.array([pitch_o(samples.astype(np.float32))[0] for samples in librosa.frames_to_samples(librosa.util.frame(audio, frame_length=512, hop_length=512))])
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: input size of pitch should be 512, not 739
```

I have tried adjusting the frame and hop sizes in the function to no avail. Perhaps there is something messing with the file between the function definition and the call, but I can't find it. The whole script can be found here if that helps: https://github.com/rcrath/wvtbl -- thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this.  I am a novice coder and an advanced beginner on DSP, just for the record.